# boto3 throws paramValidationError, while publishing

Tags: sms, amazon-sns

In the [boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.publish) docs it clearly says publish takes `PhoneNumber` as a parameter. I got following error while publishing a sms.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you're using are for boto2.4 and you're using boto3, so you need
to either provide boto3's required parameters, or downgrade to boto2.4

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sns.html

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html - those Amazon specs are for boto 2.

Comment: the parameter is `explicitly` mentioned in doc itself